# How to show image using storage folder for looping data

Tags: php, laravel, image

My image is not displaying. I'm using `Storage::` to save my image. Here how my folder looks like and `php artisan storage:link` has been created. I already try this code `{{ asset('storage/complaint' . $c->image)}}`,`{{ storage_path() . '/complaint' .$c->image}}`and `{{ url('/public/complaint' . $c->image) }}` but it seems to be not working at all.

[image]

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/report-form','ComplaintController@create');
Route::post('/report-create','ComplaintController@store');
Route::get('/report-view','ComplaintController@index');
```

**ComplaintController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Validator;
use Response;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Complaint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;

class ComplaintController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->role == 'buyer')
        {
            $complaint = Complaint::where('report_by',Auth::user()->id)->get();
            return view('buyers.complaints.index',compact('complaint'));
        }
    }

    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        return view('buyers.complaints.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if (count($request->defect_id) > 0) {
            foreach($request->defect_id as $item=>$v) {
                if (isset($request->image[$item])) {
                    $images = $request->file('image');
                    $image_resize = Image::make($images[$item]->getRealPath());
                    $image_resize->resize(900, 630);
                    $filename = $images[$item]->getClientOriginalName();

                    Storage::put($filename, $image_resize);
                    Storage::move($filename, 'public/complaint/' . $filename);
                }
                $data = array(
                    'defect_id' => $request->defect_id[$item],
                    'image' => $filename,
                    'description' => $request->description[$item],
                    'report_by' => Auth::user()->id,
                    'created_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                    'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()
                );

                Complaint::insert($data);
            }
        }
        return redirect('/report-form')->with('success','Your report is submitted!');
    }
```

**create.blade.php**

```
<div class="panel">
   <form action="/report-create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
       <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th><center>Type of Defect</center></th>
                 <th><center>Image</center></th>
                 <th><center>Description</center></th>
                 <th><center>Action</center></th>
             </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td width="20%">
                   <select class="form-control" name="defect_id[]">
                   <option value="" selected>Choose Defect</option>
                       @foreach(App\Defect::all() as $defect)
                       <option value="{{$defect->id}}">{{$defect->name}}</option>
                       @endforeach
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="image[]">
                </td>
                <td width="45%">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]">
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="add-btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
     <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></center>
      <br>
   </form>
</div>
```

```
@section('footer')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#add-btn').on('click',function () {
            var html = '';
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td><select class="form-control" name="defect_id[]"><option value="" selected>Choose Defect</option>@foreach(App\Defect::all() as $defect)<option value="{{$defect->id}}">{{$defect->name}}</option>@endforeach</td>';
            html += '<td><input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="image[]"></td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]"></td>';
            html += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="remove-btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button></td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            $('tbody').append(html);
        })
    });

    $(document).on('click','#remove-btn',function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
</script>
@stop
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="panel-heading">
   <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>List of Report</strong></h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
   <table class="table table-hover">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Defect Name</th>
             <th>Description</th>
             <th>Image</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       @foreach($complaint as $c)
           <tr class="">
                <td>{{$c->defect->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$c->description}}</td>
                <td><img src="{{ asset('storage/complaint' . $c->image)}}" class="" alt="{{$c->image}}"></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
   </table>
</div>
```

What is my mistakes?

Comment: i think you are creating your hole project via SO .?

Answer (score 0):

use `Storage::url()` ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-urls

```php
<td><img src="{{ Storage::url('complaint/' . $c->image)}}" class="" alt="{{$c->image}}"></td>
```

> **NOTE**: make sure `APP_URL=http://exmaplet.test` this is set

Comment: still the image is not displaying

Comment: what is inside `$c->image` ? and what url your getting .?

Comment: is `APP_URL=http://exmaplet.test` in .env file? If yes, mine is `APP_URL=http://localhost`

Comment: yes it is correct and what url is being generated ?

Comment: my current url for blade page is `http://localhost:8000/report-view` is that what you means?

Comment: no image `src` i m asking what is generating and your `APP_URL=http://localhost:8000` will be like this

Comment: inspect the html to see what's the generated url in the src of your image